# Exception while parsing JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I am parsing JSON data from this link:

http://twyst.in/api/v1/near/30/30

As the data is too large, I am posting only the (problem) relevant data here:

{
"info": "[{\"outlet\":{\"__v\":1,\"_id\":\"5316d59326b019ee59000026\",\"photos\":[],\"twyst_meta\":{\"recommend_list\":[],\"reviews\":[]},\"outlet_meta\":{\"links\":[],\"status\":\"active\",\"accounts\":[\"531574eeae738d654c00000a\",\"535a1a1e827651ca03000122\"]},\"attributes\":{\"dine_in\":true,\"outdoor\":true,\"air_conditioning\":\"Not Available\",\"parking\":\"Available\",\"reservation\":\"Not Required\",\"wifi\":\"Not Available\",\"tags\":[\"Pizza\",\"Pasta\",\"Italian\",\"Galleria\",\"DLF Phase 4\"],\"payment_options\":[\"cash\",\"amex\",\"visa\",\"master\"],\"cuisines\":[\"Italian\",\"Pizza\",\"Gelato\"],\"timings\":\"11 AM - 11 PM\",\"cost_for_two\":{\"min\":3,\"max\":4}},\"links\":{\"other_urls\":[],\"youtube_url\":\"\",\"twitter_url\":\"\",\"facebook_url\":\"https://www.facebook.com/pages/Crusty-gourmet-pizza-more/390843954384130\",\"website_url\":\"\"},\"contact\":{\"emails\":{\"email\":\"bob_nugent56@yahoo.com\",\"person\":\"\"},\"phones\":{\"number\":\"\",\"landline\":\"02355156616\",\"reg_mobile\":[{\"_id\":\"4639320000e4532779b17de7\",\"num\":\"9134000410\"}

This is not the end of JSON data, it goes on...

But when the following line of code is executed, I am getting a JSONException. The e.printStackTrace() method tells me that there is typeMismatch error.

```
       JSONObject object = new JSONObject(str);        //1
       JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("info");  //2
```

I have tried replacing the line 2 with the following code:

```
      JSONObject newObject = object.getJSONObject("info");
```

But here also I encountered the same problem.

I have checked the complete data, it is correct, no syntax error.
Can anybody help me with the issue ? Can the presence of double quotes before starting of JSONArray be the root of this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it will. It will interpret it as a string.

Comment: What do you mean ? Presence of double quotes will be a problem, or it will parse, I am not doing it the correct way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info` is not an array or an object. It's a string, which just happens to contain the JSON-encoded representation of another array. You will have to get that string and run it through a second JSON decoding pass:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(object.getString("info"));
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to say in the above comment. Mobile is too slow :)

Comment: @Rajat The first element of the array is an object, so you can call `getJSONObject(0)` on the array to get the object, and then use its keys, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Boann: OK I get it. I misunderstood initially.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json;
Object     info;
JSONArray  infoJsonArray;
JSONObject infoObject;
json = new JSONObject(str);

Object info= json.get("info");
if (info instanceof JSONArray) {
// It's an array
infoJsonArray = (JSONArray)info;
}
else if (info instanceof JSONObject) {
// It's an object
infoObject = (JSONObject)info;
} else {
// It's something else, like a string or number
}
```